# CloudFrontUrlSigner to sign alternative domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

So,

I've setup Cloudfront and AWS and I've created a separate `Behaviour` with `Restricted Vier Access` and and in my app I'm using `CloudFrontUrlSigner` to sign urls like this:

```
return CloudFrontUrlSigner.getSignedURLWithCannedPolicy('https://d2q5345wrel4pb8.cloudfront.net/test.jpeg', backendProperties.getAws().getKeyId(), keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec), cal.getTime());
```

and this works fine - I am able to open the url in the browser, the parameters are there and everything works fine.

Now I've also added one entry in `Alternative Domain Names`: `cdn.mycompany.com`, and so I try to sign the URL again with the same code:

```
return CloudFrontUrlSigner.getSignedURLWithCannedPolicy('https://cdn.mycompany.com/test.jpeg', backendProperties.getAws().getKeyId(), keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec), cal.getTime());
```

but the url in the browser says:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access denied</Message>
</Error>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.
My `cdn.mycompany.com` CNAME record in Cloudflare had Proxied=TRUE. Once I set it to FALSE it started to work fine.